# Issue with saving an apex class

Tags: apex

## Create Class

```
public class OuterClass {
    protected Integer i = 0 ;
    public class InnerClass {
        public InnerClass() { 
            i = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Unable to save class which should be saved as per the below doc:-

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm

Comment: You can't access `instance` variables like that, ony `static` variables.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the documentation for this :

> An inner class behaves like a static Java inner class, but doesn’t
>   require the static keyword. An inner class can have instance member
>   variables like an outer class, but there is no implicit pointer to an
>   instance of the outer class (using the this keyword).

[Static class in apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm)

so in your case if you want to access value of outer class you can create instance of outerclass and get the value

```
Public Class OuterClass
{

  Protected Integer i = 0 ;

 Public Class InnerClass
{
  public integer intinner;
  Public InnerClass()
  { 
       outerclass obj = new outerclass();
       intinner = obj.i;
       system.debug('*****************'+ intinner);
   }
 }

}
```

Comment: Might be worth adding that if OP wants to access **i** from the parent, the variable either needs to be static or they need to pass the parent into the children.

Answer (score 0):

Given the way inner classes work in Apex (as Himanshu has explained) a couple of common patterns are:

```
// Copy a value on construction of the inner class
public Class OuterClass {
    private Integer i = 0;
    public Class InnerClass {
        Integer i;
        public InnerClass(Integer i) { 
            this.i = i;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
        InnerClass inner = new Inner(i);
    ...
}
```

which means there are separate copies of the values or:

```
// Copy a reference on construction of the inner class
public Class OuterClass {
    private Mutable m = new Mutable();
    public Class InnerClass {
        Mutable m ;
        public InnerClass(Mutable m) { 
            this.m = m;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
        InnerClass = new InnerClass(m);
    ...
}
```

which means changes to the referenced object made via the inner or outer classes are also seen in the outer or inner class respectively.

A version of the latter pattern that approximates a Java non-static inner class is:

```
// Copy a reference to the outer class on construction of the inner class
public Class OuterClass {
    public Class InnerClass {
        OuterClass outer;
        public InnerClass(OuterClass outer) { 
            this.outer = outer;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
        InnerClass inner = new InnerClass(this);
    ...
}
```

where the inner class just needs to qualify its references to the outer class with an `outer.` prefix.